# What is this extra partition that has appeared suddenly in macOS and how to delete it?

Tags: macos, partition, big-sur

macOS BigSur 11.2.3 (20D91) / MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) has suddenly generated a new 22GB partition. I noticed this yesterday when 22GB suddenly disappeared and I started to receive low disk space warnings. It seems to me this partition is for some update that possibly has gone wrong?

I have upgraded Big Sur as soon as it was available so that is some time ago. This partition is more recent. A week ago I partiotioned some USB drives and this partition did not show up back then. Also I did reinstall XCode recently but it worked fine.

I cant remove it from he minus sign. Should I boot from network and delete this or will deleting it create problems? Is there a "correct way" to fix this?

[image: Screenshot from disctool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite normal under BigSur and it is not a partition, but a snapshot of your drive. E.g. mine looks quite similar:

[image: Partitions]

There is nothing you need to worry about and you should not try to delete it. This exact layout has been also discussed in [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252059387), on [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/strange-partition-after-upgradeding-to-big-sur.2267673/) and on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jx4uhc/does_anyone_know_what_this_nightmare_is/).

To quote from reddit (user "Advanced_Path"):

> Big Sur changes the way how updates are done. Now that the System volume is basically immutable, the way an update is done is with APFS snapshots. The system takes a snapshot of the base volume, updates the necessary file and from that moment forward, it boots from that snapshot.

Furher, I can recommend [this article](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/13/big-sur-boot-volume-layout/).